# Getting an error trying to pull out text using Google Sheets and importxml()

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of links in Google Sheets. I want to tell if a page is producing an error message using `importxml`

As an example, this works fine

```
=importxml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_T", "//td/b")
```

i.e. it looks for td, and pulls out b (which are postcodes in Canada)

But this code that looks for the error message does not work:

```
=importxml("https://www.awwwards.com/error1/", "//div/h1" )
```

I want it to pull out the "**THE PAGE YOU WERE LOOKING FOR DOESN'T EXIST.**"

...on this page https://www.awwwards.com/error1/

I'm getting a `Resource at URL not found error`. What could I be doing wrong? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

after quick trial and error with default formulae:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.awwwards.com/error1/", "//*")
```

---

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.awwwards.com/error1/", "table", 1)
```

---

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.awwwards.com/error1/", "list", 1)
```

---

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.awwwards.com/error1/")
```

it seems that the website is not possible to be scraped in Google Sheets by any means (regular formulae)

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve the value of `THE PAGE YOU WERE LOOKING FOR DOESN'T EXIST.` from the URL of `https://www.awwwards.com/error1/`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that the page of your URL is `Error 404 (Not Found)`. So in this case, the status code of `404` is returned. I thought that by this, the built-in functions like `IMPORTXML` might not be able to retrieve the HTML data.

So as one workaround, how about using a custom function with UrlFetchApp? When UrlFetchApp is used, the HTML data can be retrieved even when the status code is `404`.

#### Sample script for custom function:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Spreadsheet. And please put `=SAMPLE("https://www.awwwards.com/error1")` to a cell on the Spreadsheet. By this, the script is run.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  return UrlFetchApp
    .fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true})
    .getContentText()
    .match(/<h1>([\w\s\S]+)<\/h1>/)[1]
    .toUpperCase();
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This custom function is for the URL of `https://www.awwwards.com/error1`. When you use this for other URL, the expected results might not be able to be retrieved. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

  > muteHttpExceptions: If true the fetch doesn't throw an exception if the response code indicates failure, and instead returns the HTTPResponse. The default is false.
- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.