# Google Sheets - [Resource at URL not found]

Tags: google-sheets

Recently having issue with google sheets getting info from yahoo finance.

`=if(isblank(B4),"",ImportXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B4&"/history?p="&B4, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[6]"))`

*Cell B4 is ticker, example : [7113.KL]

Anyone encounter this?

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `IMPORT` functions doesn't work on the link you provided. It might be that the data is javascript generated and it is a current limitation of `IMPORT` functions.

Easiest way to circumvent this is to find another site that its data isn't javascript generated. Such as this [one](https://www.investingport.com/).

#### Formula:

`=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investingport.com/quotes/7113.KL/", "//div[@class='col-md-6']/span"),1,1)`

Since your `B4` contains `7113.KL` and you check the `B4` first
, then adjusted formula is:

`=if(isblank(B4),"", INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investingport.com/quotes/"&B4&"/", "//div[@class='col-md-6']/span"),1,1))`

#### Sample output:

[image: output]

#### Alternative:

- Another way is to do it via Apps Script using [`UrlFetchApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060252/14606045)

Comment: What about the price change?

Comment: =IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML( "https://www.investingport.com/quotes/"&B4&"/",  "//*[@class=""D(ib) Mend(22px)""]/span[2]"),  "\+?(.*?\s)")))

Comment: After trying a day, I think that investing port site is not accurate as the price delayed and not even change after market close, and price is different from my local market price. Example 0150.KL (FINTEC), local price is 0.075, investing port show 0.08.

Comment: I'm sorry about that @DaxmenCha if the site doesn't provide the correct data. I am unable to find alternatives that has "7113.KL" in its url and at the same time has correct data. Some of the sites I found were actually having the name of the company on the url instead of name and we know it isn't reliable to use that as identifier. You can try using Apps Script instead if you want a more reliable way of getting the value. I referenced it above. If it isn't enough, feel free to scour the net on how to use `UrlFetchApp`

Comment: if you want the price change, you just need to change `1,1` to `1,2` in the formula. it will return something like this `+0.13 (+2.50%)`. If you want to have the left side, use `split`.  `=INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investingport.com/quotes/7113.KL/", "//div[@class='col-md-6']/span"),1,2), " "),1,1)`. This will return `+0.13`. If you want the second, use `=INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.investingport.com/quotes/7113.KL/", "//div[@class='col-md-6']/span"),1,2), " "),1,2)`. This will return `(+2.50%)`

Comment: I think I found out why the price different. Sites like Investing Port, Morningstar, and Barron's does not show half a cent, therefore the price shown is rounded up. I am very very new to coding, just at the very beginning of learning how to do coding on google sheet. Can you help me find is there any code that I could use to extract data from certain sites?

https://finance.yahoo.com/
https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/
https://klse.i3investor.com/index.jsp

Comment: Hi @DaxmenCha, if you want the price: `=importxml("https://klse.i3investor.com/index.jsp", "//div[@id='ind0']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")`, if the price change, `=importxml("https://klse.i3investor.com/index.jsp", "//div[@id='ind0']/table/tbody/tr/td[3]")`, if the price change in percentage, `=importxml("https://klse.i3investor.com/index.jsp", "//div[@id='ind0']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]")`

Comment: The code you send to me is for the KLSE index. What about for some stock? Example TOP GLOVE CORP BHD [KLSE: TOPGLOV (7113)]

Comment: I have column B for the stock code, I tired this =if(isblank(B3),"",importxml("https://https://klse.i3investor.com/quoteservlet.jsp?sa=ss&q="&C3&", "//div[@id='ind0']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"))"))

Comment: If B3 = 7113, Price is `=importxml("https://klse.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/"&B3&".jsp", "//table[@id='stockhdr']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")` and Price Change is `=index(importxml("https://klse.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/"&B3&".jsp", "//table[@id='stockhdr']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"),1,2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229740/discussion-between-nazia-and-daxmen-cha).